# How do you threaten diagonals with Reach?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, reach

According to the rules on [measuring diagonals](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/Combat/#Diagonals) in the Pathfinder SRD:

> When measuring distance, the first diagonal counts as 1 square, the second counts as 2 squares, the third counts as 1, the fourth as 2, and so on.

A medium character with a reach weapon threatens 2 squares away (10 feet). The first diagonal is five feet, so my character does not threaten that square, but the second diagonal is 15 feet away, so I don't threaten that either.

Does this mean an opponent can step inside my reach without ever stepping in a square I threaten and thus never provoking an Attack of Opportunity just by walking down my diagonal line?

This feels like a serious design flaw, so I feel like I'm missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not tracked the errata that this FAQ talks about, but...

> [As an exception to the way that diagonals normally work, a creature with 10 feet of reach threatens the second diagonal. These changes will be reflected in the next errata.](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9sp8)